# Get content of a list<T> in oData Controller

Tags: .net, odata, asp.net-mvc-5

In my oDataController I want to get the content of a list. If I debug the following example I can see, that the IQueryable "q" actually contains correct content.

```
public class HousesController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("Houses")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetHouses()
    {
        Yard y = new Yard();

        //...code that gets "bhl", what is a list<HouseViewModel>-Type

        IQueryable<HouseViewModel> q = bhl.AsQueryable();           

        return Ok(q);
    }
}
```

But this gives me an 500 Internal Server error as HTTP Response. No more. Any ideas what I can try or how I could get a more detailed error message?

Thanks :-)

Edit:

Even this leads to the problem:

```
        List<PersonViewModel> test = new List<PersonViewModel>();
        test.Add(new PersonViewModel());
        return Ok(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:
- how many items are in the 'q' object? Is it possible that your code exceed the http limit traffic? Try to add .Take(5) to your query, for example, to limit the object returned to the client
- try to return Ok(q.ToList()) - maybe the list must be materialized before returning?

Comment: There are only 7 house objects, so I do not think point 1 is an issue. I also tried .ToList(). Unfortunately without any luck :-(